# DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: python, oracle

please help new to coding

I keep getting an error

> in getSidsWithStatusX
>       sip.execute(query) DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

```
def getSidsWithStatusX(startDate, statusX, endDate=None):
    query = cfg.GET_STARTDATE_QUERY.format(startDate=startDate)
    if (endDate):
        query += cfg.GET_ENDDATE_QUERY.format(endDate=endDate)

    query += cfg.GET_STATUSID_QUERY.format(statusX=statusX)
    logger.debug(query)

    sip = rdb.getCursor('sip')
    sip.execute(query)
    data = sip.fetchall()
    sip.rollback()
    sids = []
```

Im passing :

```
GET_STARTDATE_QUERY = """
                        select sid
                        from contact_requests
                        where entry_date > '{startDate:'%d-%b-%Y'}'
                    """


GET_ENDDATE_QUERY = """
                    and entry_date < '{endDate:'%d-%b-%Y'}'
                """


GET_STATUSID_QUERY = """
                           and request_status_id = '{statusX:s}'
                       """
```

Comment: What's the query being executed. Add that to the question.

Comment: Typical scenario for debugging. Impossible to help without seeing the actual sql query itself. What does „logger.debug(query)“ print to the log?

Comment: @AydinK. This is the error it's printing                                     in getSidsWithStatusX sip.execute(query) DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have quotes around the format specification in the format string. Those quotes are being copied into the result, so you end up with two sets of quotes, one from the quote before `{` and after `}`, and the other from the quotes around `%d-%b-%Y`.

```
GET_STARTDATE_QUERY = """
                        select sid
                        from contact_requests
                        where entry_date > '{startDate:%d-%b-%Y}'
                    """
```